Suppose $1\leq p_1<p_2<+\infty$ and $\mu$ a finite measure, then $\mathscr{L}^{p_2}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)\subseteq\mathscr{L}^{p_1}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$
I need to prove the following result:

Suppose $1\leq p_1<p_2<+\infty$ and $\mu$ a finite measure, then $\mathscr{L}^{p_2}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)\subseteq\mathscr{L}^{p_1}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $f\in\mathscr{L}^{p_2}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Then $f$ is an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function such that $|f|^{p_2}$ is integrable. So $\int(|f|^{p_2})^+d\mu = \int|f|^{p_2} < +\infty$. For $x$ in $X$ that $|f(x)|\geq1$, we have $|f(x)|^{p_1}\leq|f(x)|^{p_2}$. For $x$ in $X$ such that $0\leq|f(x)|<1$, we have $|f(x)|^{p_1}<1$. Define a function $g$ by letting
\begin{align*}
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x)\quad &\text{if $|f(x)|\geq1$},\\
\\
1\quad &\text{if $0\leq|f(x)|<1$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $|f(x)|^{p_1}\leq|g(x)|^{p_2}$ for all $x$ in $X$. Define a function $h$ by letting
\begin{align*}
h(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x)\quad &\text{if $|f(x)|\geq1$},\\
\\
0\quad &\text{if $0\leq|f(x)|<1$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $g(x)=h(x)+\chi_{A}$, where $A=\{x\in X:0\leq|f(x)|<1\}$, and $|g(x)|^{p_2} = |h(x)|^{p_2} + \chi_{A}$ for all $x$ in $X$.
We prove that $|h|^{p_2}$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. For each $t\geq1$, the set $\{x\in X:|h(x)|<t\} = \{x\in X:|f(x)|<t\}\in\mathscr{A}$, because $|f|$ is integrable and so $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. For each $t<1$, the set $\{x\in X:|h(x)|<t\} = \{x\in X:|f(x)|<s\} \in \mathscr{A}$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $|h|$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable (and real-valued), and so $|h|^{p_2}$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable.
Since $|h|^{p_2}$ and $|f|^{p_2}$ are both nonnegative real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions such that $|h(x)|^{p_2}\leq|f(x)|^{p_2}$ holds at each $x$ in $X$, it follows that $\int|h|^{p_2}d\mu \leq \int|f|^{p_2}d\mu < +\infty$. So, $|h|^{P_2}$ is integrable. Since $\mu$ is a finite measure on the measurable space $(X,\mathscr{A})$, it follows that $\int\chi_{A}d\mu = \mu(A) < +\infty$, and so $\chi_{A}$ is integrable. Therefore, $int|g|^{p_2}d\mu = \int(|h|^{p_2}+\chi_{A})d\mu = \int|h|^{p_2}d\mu + \int\chi_{A}d\mu < +\infty$. Since $|f|^{p_1}$ and $|g|^{p_2}$ are nonnegative real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$ such that $|f(x)|^{p_1}\leq|g(x)|^{p_2}$ holds at each $x$ in $X$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int|f|^{p_1}d\mu \leq \int|g|^{p_2}d\mu < +\infty.
\end{align*}
Hence, $|f|^{p_1}$ is integrable, $f\in\mathscr{L}^{p_1}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.

Is my attempt correct? I am unconfident about the part proving $|h|^{p_2}$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable (e.g., "for each $t<1$, the set $\{x\in X:|h(x)|<t\} = \{x\in X:|f(x)|<s\} \in \mathscr{A}$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$"). Also I'm not sure if there are mistakes elsewhere. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check my proof! Thank you very much!


Definition$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $p$ satisfy $1\leq p<+\infty$. Then $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is the set of all $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions $f$ such that $|f|^p$ is integrable.


Reference:
Example 3.3.5 from Measure Theory by Donald Cohn.

The Hólder inequality  applied to $f$ and $1$  with $p=p_2/p_1$ implies the inclusion.

@RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much for your comment! Just want to make sure I get your point: Is the answer I posted below what you meant?

Thanks to @RyszardSzwarc's comment.
Let $f\in\mathscr{L}^{p_2}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, then $\int|f|^{p_2}d\mu<+\infty$. Let $p=\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ and $q=\frac{p_2}{p_2-p_1}$. Then $p,q\in[1,+\infty]$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Since $$\int\Big||f|^{p_1}\Big|^{p}d\mu = \int\Big||f|^{p_1}\Big|^{\frac{p_2}{p_1}}d\mu = \int|f|^{p_2}d\mu < +\infty,$$ it follows that $|f|^{p_1}\in\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Let $g=1$. Then
$$
\int|g|^qd\mu = \int|1|^qd\mu = \int1d\mu = \mu(X) < +\infty
$$
because $\mu$ is finite. Thus, $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Now by Hölder's inequality,
\begin{align*}
\int\Big||f|^{p_1}g\Big|d\mu &= \int|f|^{p_1}d\mu\\
&\leq \||f|^{p_1}\|_p\|g\|_q\\
&= \left(\int\Big||f|^{p_1}\Big|^pd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \left(\int|g|^qd\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
&= \left(\int|f|^{p_1\cdot\frac{p_2}{p_1}}d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\mu^{\frac{1}{q}}(X)\\
&= \left(\int|f|^{p_2}d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\mu^{\frac{1}{q}}(X)\\
&< +\infty.
\end{align*}
Thus, $|f|^{p_1}$ is integrable and $f\in\mathscr{L}^{p_1}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.

Hölder's inequality$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $p$ and $q$ satisfy $1\leq p\leq+\infty$ and $1\leq q\leq+\infty$, and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. If $f\in\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and $g\in\mathscr{L}^q(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, then $fg$ belongs to $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and satisfies $\int|fg|d\mu\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_q$.

That's exactly what I meant. (+) Besides the proof gives $$|f|{p_1}\le \mu(X)^{(p_2-p_1)/(p_1p_2)}|f|{p_2}$$

@RyszardSzwarc Thank you very much! And indeed $$\int|f|^{p_1}d\mu\leq\left(\int|f|^{p_2}d\mu\right)^{\frac{p_1}{p_2}}\mu(X)^{1-\frac{p_1}{p_2}}$$ which implies $$\left(\int|f|^{p_1}d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p_1}}\leq\left(\int|f|^{p_2}d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{p_2}}\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p_1}-\frac{1}{p_2}}$$ which implies $$|f|{p_1}\leq\mu(X)^{\frac{p_2-p_1}{p_1p_2}}|f|{p_2}.$$ But could you please illustrate why is this an important result?

It gives a comparison of the norms.
